# Check function parameters for existence and type in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Supposed I have a function defined such as:

```
var x = function (options, callback) { /* ... */ }
```

`options` needs to have properties `foo` and `bar`, where `foo` shall be of type `number`, and `bar` of type `string`.

So, basically, I could check this using the following code:

```
var x = function (options, callback) {
  if (!options) { throw new Error('options is missing.'); }
  if (!options.foo) { throw new Error('foo is missing.'); }
  if (!options.bar) { throw new Error('bar is missing.'); }
  if (!callback) { throw new Error('callback is missing.'); }
  // ...
}
```

But this only checks for existence, not yet for correct types. Of course I can add further checks, but this soon becomes lengthy, and not so well readable. Once we start talking about optional parameters, it gets a mess, with parameter-shifting and so on …

What is the best way to deal with this (supposed that you want to check it)?

**UPDATE**

To clarify my question: I know that there is the `typeof` operator, and I also know how to deal with optional parameters. But I have to do all these checks manually, and this - for sure - is not the *best* we can come up with.

The goal of my question was: Is there a ready-made function / library / whatever that you can tell that you are expecting five parameters of specific types, some mandatory, some optional, and the function / library / whatever does the checks and the mapping for you, so that all this comes down to a one-liner?

Basically, something such as:

```
var x = function (options, callback) {
  verifyArgs({
    options: {
      foo: { type: 'number', mandatory: true },
      bar: { type: 'string', mandatory: true }
    },
    callback: { type: 'function', mandatory: false }
  });
  // ...
};
```

Comment: You could use a loop and have an object tell the types: validateObj = { "foo":"number","bar":"text" }

Comment: Is there a pre-made function that does that? Of course it's possible to create it for yourself, but if there's already a widely used solution, I'd prefer sticking to it.

Comment: Use the typeof operator

Comment: Please see the updated part of my question, a simple `typeof` is not what I want (and I am fully aware of this solution, but it soon becomes a mess, when you have lots of parameters you want to check).

Comment: @GoloRoden With vanilla JavaScript, you're on your own for this. You could give [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) a try, which handles many of the type checks.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski TypeScript is not an option in this case, but thanks for pointing this out anyway.

Comment: @cHao I don't want to worry myself crazy, but there are situations where it perfectly makes sense to check these things. What I want is to fail early, hence the checks, and not just use it as whatever I need it to be …

Comment: @GoloRoden: You may want to reconsider TypeScript, then.  As dynamically typed as JavaScript is, it will resist you at every turn.  Seriously, it's so easy to subvert any type system you create, even accidentally, that it's typically not worth the trouble in the first place.

Comment: You have seen that I wrote (two comments above) that TypeScript is not an option in this case?

Comment: @GoloRoden: Then neither is overcaring about types.

Comment: @cHao You have absolutely no idea of the context, but feel destined to question my reasons :-/. Believe me (or leave it): TypeScript is not an option, but I *do need* type checking.

Comment: @GoloRoden: I'm questioning your reasons because *every single time* i have ever seen someone who says they absolutely need type checking in JS, it was because they were stuck in a strict-typing mindset and were trying to force JS into that mold.  It doesn't work.  All it does is drive you crazy trying, while basically outlawing a lot of what makes JS as powerful as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a library that does what I want by myself, it's called [ArgueJS](https://github.com/zvictor/ArgueJS):

```
function range(){ 
  arguments = __({start: [Number, 0], stop: Number, step: [Number, 1]})

  for(var i = arguments.start; i < arguments.stop; i += arguments.step)
    console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

javascript has `typeof`

```
console.log( typeof '123' ); // string
console.log( typeof 123 ); // number
console.log( typeof undefinedVar); // undefined


var x = function (options, callback) {
  if (typeof options =='undefined' { throw new Error('options is missing.'); }
  if (typeof options.foo !='number') { throw new Error('foo is missing.'); }
  if (typeof options.bar !='string') { throw new Error('bar is missing.'); }
  if (typeof callback!= 'function') { throw new Error('callback is missing.'); }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this:

```
var x = function (options, callback) {
    var options = options || {};
    if (typeof options.foo != 'number') {
        throw new Error('foo need to be a number.');
    }
    if (typeof options.bar != 'string') {
        throw new Error('bar need to be a string.');
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Ftypeof)

```
// Numbers
typeof 37 === 'number';
typeof 3.14 === 'number';
typeof Math.LN2 === 'number';
typeof Infinity === 'number';
typeof NaN === 'number'; // Despite being "Not-A-Number"
typeof Number(1) === 'number'; // but never use this form!
```

...

Comment: `typeof new Number(3.14) === 'object'`.

Comment: *"Despite being "Not-A-Number""* Just to make sure: This is not an error in JS (like `typeof null`), this is in compliance with the [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). `NaN` is a special number value.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(myProp)) { //to check whether mentioned property exist
    if (typeof myObj[myProp] == "string") { //or integer
        // your code to be executed!!!
    } else {
        //ERROR!!!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See these examples for checking the type, string or integer:

```
if(typeof(somevar) === 'string') alert('string');
if(typeof(somevar)==="number" && Math.round(somevar) == somevar) alert('is int');
```

Comment: `typeof somevar` is the preferred syntax. It is an operator and not a function

Comment: Also, the Match.round(), why? Maybe 12.4 should be correct too (though typeof might need a change to float). This is an action which doesn't add allot and does slow down

Answer (score 0):

While this is not *exactly* the idea behind javascript's type model, I usually used a `for`-loop to iterate over the data members of my to-check-object:

```
/* (.startsWith has to be implementes somehow) */
for (key in my_object_with_data) {
    if (!key.startsWith(typeof my_object_with_data[key]+"_") {
        /* The member "key" has wrong type. */
    }
}
```

The members of the object have to be named `number_a` for example to check it's type for being a number.

Additional validation can be done via some generic check methods, that can be applied inside the for loop according to the `typeof` value.